# Поиск объекта по iд который берется из переменной

Tags: javascript, jquery

После ajax запроса получаю переменную **c0**.
Необходимо найти и удалить элемент если его id равен **c0**.

А если быть еще точнее, то вот что нужно удалить:

$('#dialogBody div #**c0**').remove

Помогите грамотно составить код.

Не знаю как именно составить конструкцию из информации передаваемой текстом и информацией взятой из переменной.
Не знаю как именно найти элемент с id равным значению переменной.

Comment: `$("#" + c0).remove();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы подобных вопросов не возникало, запомните:

1. id ставить нужный уникальный, это же id. Не в коем случае нельзя допускать такого что бы на одной странице было два и более элемента с идентичными id.
2. Если нужно присвоить какой то общий признак, используют class.

> Не знаю как именно найти элемент с id равным значению переменной.

Одно из решений. При условии что вы соблюдаете то что я написал выше.

```
$("#" + c0).remove();
```